# Link to Service Cloud Console from Email link

Tags: service-cloud-console

Is it possible to construct a link that opens a Visualforce page as a Service Cloud console tab instead of opening it in a window that has the single tab at the top that says "Back to Console"? Our users are heavy console users and they want to go to console from an email link.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open an entity within the console and not separately, then you can use:

> https://[instance].salesforce.com/ui/support/servicedesk/ServiceDeskPage#/[entity_id]

Where the [entity_id] can be anything, like Contact id, Account Id, Case Id, etc

See details at https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176454&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this example

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_sample_vf.htm

```
function openPrimaryTab() {
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined, 
           'http://www.salesforce.com', true, 'salesforce');
    }

    //The callback function that openSubtab will call once it's got the ID for its primary tab
    var callOpenSubtab=function callOpenSubtab(result) {
        sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, 
           'http://www.yahoo.com', true, 'yahoo');
    };
```

Comment: That works when linking from a page in Salesforce. I want to link from an email.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a way to make this work. Finally I've checked urls for console and found below link to work if user is logged in to Salesforce and has open console application. (User does not has to keep console tab open but when he opens salesforce it should open in console app)

```
https://[your-salesforce-org-domain].salesforce.com/console#https%3A%2F%2F[your-salesforce-org-domain].salesforce.com%2Fapex%2F[your-visualforcepage-name]%3F[parameter1]%3D[parameter1-value]%26[parameter2]%3D[parameter2-value]
```

Basically it is your `salesforce-domain/console#[your visualforce page in your salesforce domain in encoded form]`

This links opens console with given Visualforce page.